# Updating old add-on with portal_tool from Plone 2.1 (Archetypes) to 4.3 (Dexterity)

Tags: plone

I'm trying to update an plone 2.1 add-on with 2 content types (Archetypes) to Plone 4 (Dexterity).

One of this content types (foo) acts like a portal_tool, which is a unique 'container' where the another content type (bar) with some fields must be added (and just on this 'container').

I'm not sure if there's a way to do this on Dexterity, as before on Archetypes. Also, is a custom portal_tools, in this case, a viable way in Plone 4.x+ or is deprecated?

Here some excerpts (from AT):

foo.py:

```
class foo(UniqueObject, BaseFolder):
    ...
    __implements__ = (getattr(UniqueObject,'__implements__',()),) + (getattr(BaseFolder,'__implements__',()),)
    ...
    allowed_content_types = ['bar']
    ...
    def __init__(self, id=None):
        BaseFolder.__init__(self,'portal_foo')
        self.setTitle('Foo')
    ...
```

bar.py:

```
class bar(BaseContent):
    ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if creating a custom Dexterity content type that extends `UniqueObject` could work someway (probably not), but using a Plone content type for a single point of configuration is a very old and deprecated way to go.

My suggestion is move your configurations to the [Plone registry](http://docs.plone.org/develop/plone/functionality/controlpanel.html).

Comment: Thanks for the response! Actually i'm creating this add-on from scratch in Plone 4.3. I'm checking this right now.

Comment: I finished this creating a folder as a content type (foo) and restrict the addition of 'bar' content type on this folder. The only 'inconvenience' of this is that 'foo' is can be added anywhere on the site, which was not the original behavior ('foo' was unique). Anyway thanks for your answer :).